# Load options list once and render it to multiple select boxes on client side?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my Rails 3.2 app, I have something similar to an album page which shows many photos. Under each of the photos is a select box where the user can choose from a number of options, formatted something like this:

```
<select id="photo_1">
  <option value=value_1>Name of Value 1</option>
  ...
  <option value=value_n>Name of Value N</option>
</select>
```

The problem is, the list of values is very long (100s of possibilities), but exactly the same for each photo. Since each Album could possibly have dozens of photos, it seems inefficient to have the server send the full list each time a photo is loaded to the page. Is there a more efficient way to do this such as, for example, loading

```
  <option value=value_1>Name of Value 1</option>
  ...
  <option value=value_n>Name of Value N</option>
```

just once to the Album page when it is generated (perhaps as a hidden field), and then using jQuery/javascript to populate it into the photo's unique  tags on the client side, when the photo is loaded to the page? (NOTE: Photos load dynamically, so some may load after the initial load of the Album page, as the user uploads them.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if the `<select>`s that require this had a common class, but this works for any `<select>` whose ID begins with `photo` (although you should probably use `name` rather than `id`).

```
$(function () {
    $("select[id^=photo]").each(function () {
       $(this).html($("#hidden_select").html());
    });
});​
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/ULpEH/1/)

Comment: have you tested this cross browser? IE won't likely accept `<option>` as child of DIV

Comment: You're right, I've replaced the hidden DIV with a hidden SELECT. See updated fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You can just copy the options to the other elements

**HTML**

```
<select id="photo_1">
  <option value="value_">Pick</option>    
  <option value="value_1">Name of Value 1</option>
  <option value="value_2">Name of Value 2</option>
  <option value="value_3">Name of Value 3</option>
</select>
<select class="copy"></select>
<select class="copy"></select>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var mainSelectOptions = $("#photo_1 option").clone();
var selects = jQuery(".copy").append(mainSelectOptions);
```

Example: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TqDHe/)

Comment: It's probably easier with a separate, hidden element to use as the template. That way the script that creates all the SELECTs doesn't have to special-case the first one.

Comment: @Barmar And your example will not validate since options are supposed to be in a select element, not a div. Instead of adding classes it can be as simple as selecting the first and ignoring the first in the selectors.

Comment: Thanks--great answer, but I tend to agree with Barmar: it was easier to use a separate, hidden element as the template and not special case the first select, especially since my application was rendering all the photo partials in the same way (an empty select without options).

Comment: If you stick the options into a "template" make sure it validates. :) And the id^=photo is slower that a common class or element.